# I want to deploy node js project to netlify. there is no routes in it this is a simple socket.io code how to do so?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, netlify

My netlify.toml file :

`[build] functions = "netlify-functions" command = "npm run build"`

Error i encountered with :

D:\Projects\live_streaming\live_streaming_backend>netlify deploy
Please provide a publish directory (e.g. "public" or "dist" or "."):
? Publish directory D:\Projects\live_streaming\live_streaming_backend
Deploy path:        D:\Projects\live_streaming\live_streaming_backend
Functions path:     D:\Projects\netlify-functions
Configuration path: D:\Projects\live_streaming\live_streaming_backend\netlify.toml
Functions folder "D:\Projects\netlify-functions" specified but it doesn't exist! Will proceed without deploying functions
Deploying to draft URL...
»   Warning: JSONHTTPError: Not Found 404
»   Warning:
{
"name": "JSONHTTPError",
"status": 404,
"json": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Not Found"
}
}

»   JSONHTTPError: Not Found

how to solve this issue ?